# Theme Changer using css html

Tags: javascript, html, css, radio-button, styling

I need to make a calculator using front-end libraries but I'm unable to make a theme changer button as shown in the image. I've tried to figure out what is missing but I'm still confused how to achieve that.

I want to make radio button like on-off switch as shown in this code [enter link description here](https://calculator-app-kappa.vercel.app/)

```css
#theme-switch {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.theme-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.input {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: #213a6b;
}

.item-2 {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #213a6b;
}

.item {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.make-inline {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="theme-switch">
          <div>THEME</div>
          <div class="make-inline">
            <div class="theme-wrapper">
              <div>
                <label for="1">1</label>
              </div>
              <div class="input item">
                <input type="radio" id="1"></input>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="theme-wrapper">
              <div>
                <label for="2">2</label>
              </div>
              <div class="item-2">
                <input type="radio" id="2"></input>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="theme-wrapper">
              <div>
                <label for="3">3</label>
              </div>
              <div class="input item">
                <input type="radio" id="3"></input>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iINVp.jpg)

Comment: What's the goal here, to change the theme when clicking radio button 1 2, and 3?

Comment: Yeah, I've mentioned a  link it should work like that program.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use some JavaScript for this.

Setup some classes for each theme. Then use JavaScript to toggle the theme class.

```js
document.getElementById("theme-1").addEventListener("click", function () {
  var e = document.getElementById("target");
  e.classList.add("theme-1");
  e.classList.remove("theme-2");
  e.classList.remove("theme-3");
});

document.getElementById("theme-2").addEventListener("click", function () {
  var e = document.getElementById("target");
  e.classList.add("theme-2");
  e.classList.remove("theme-1");
  e.classList.remove("theme-3");
});

document.getElementById("theme-3").addEventListener("click", function () {
  var e = document.getElementById("target");
  e.classList.add("theme-3");
  e.classList.remove("theme-1");
  e.classList.remove("theme-2");
});
```

```css
.some-class {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.some-class.theme-1 {
  color: green;
}
.some-class.theme-2 {
  color: red;
}
.some-class.theme-3 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="target" class="some-class">Hello</div>
<label for="theme-1">1</label><input id="theme-1" type="radio" name="theme" />
<label for="theme-2">2</label><input id="theme-2" type="radio" name="theme" />
<label for="theme-3">3</label><input id="theme-3" type="radio" name="theme" />
```

Comment: Was gonna do the same thing use this and work on it. it's pretty easy to achieve what you are looking for if you base it on this example.

Comment: I worried about the layout most. I will add functionality later once the layout is completed.